# Javascript Add a mouseup event to the chart and use that instead of '3' key

Tags: javascript

I would like to modify the example below to add a mouseup event to the chart and use that instead of '3' key. So, when the user clicks mouse button while on the chart, server code will send new data.

```
// Now, setup the keyboard event function
window.onload = function(){
 document.addEventListener("keypress", mKey);
}

function mKey(e) {

     if (e.key == "1") // transform chart
     {
       my_bar = !my_bar; //change the state, then transform
       if (my_bar ==true)
         chart.transform('bar');
       else
         chart.transform('line');
     }
     else if (e.key == "2") // transform chart
     {
       my_spline = !my_spline; //change the state, then transform
       if (my_spline==true)
         chart.transform('spline');
       else
         chart.transform('line');
     }
     else if (e.key == "3") // send message to Shiny
    {
       Shiny.onInputChange("clickedkey", [e.key, Math.random()]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
function mouseup(){
    Shiny.onInputChange("mouseup", [Math.random()]);
}

window.onload = function(){
     document.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);
     document.addEventListener("keypress", mKey);
}
```

Then get rid of the `3` key else if statement